# Swift IOS - text fields, segmented controls, etc are not editable on scrollview

Tags: swift, autolayout, scrollview

I need a scrollable view for a long data entry form.  I added a scroll view and on top of the scroll view i added a view (lets call it contentView).  I added text fields and segmented controls to the contentView.  I added autolayout to get the textfields and others controls to hold their position regardless of iphone size.

The scrollview scrolls fine but not of the fields are editable.

Any idea as to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Not enough information. Or you can paste some screenshot. Top means ```contentView``` is subview of UIScrollView? If so, i think your layout is wrong, try to change the background color of contentView to see if your controls is in the contentView's frame. If it's out of contentView, won't 'editable'.

Comment: @WilliamHu Yes contentView is a subview of UIScrollView.  I changed the color of the UIScrollView to yellow and it appears that the controls (textbox, segmented controls) are inside the UIScrollView and NOT the contentView.   How can I fix the setup?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently according your comment, your layout isn't enough, try to set it like the image below. The orange color is `contentView`'s `backgroundcolor`[image],

Comment: So putting constraints on the contentView keeps contentView smaller than the scrollView?  In my example, why are the controls on the scrollView and not the contentView.

Comment: Because scrollview is special the size depends on content size, you haven't set the constraints for your contentView. Here is a tutorial http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/